# i want to slide div with id="banner"?

Tags: jquery, css, html

i want that on click of arrow-glow image the apDiv1 is hidden and banner slides on the page from right to left.which libraries should i add and also on adding the library of jqueryui it says "jquery is undefined"??
i am very new to jquery please provide with the help and let me know the changes in my code...
thanks in advance

http://jsfiddle.net/UVZw2/

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:Silver;
}

#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    left: 0px;
}
#apDiv2 {   
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
#fontmain {
    font-size:250px;
    margin-left:400px;
    padding: 0;
}
#fonttag {
    font-size:30px;
    margin-left:480px;
    padding: 0;
}

#apDiv3 {
    margin-top:260px;
    font-size:90%;
    margin-left:500px;
}
#apDiv4 {
    margin-top:250px;
    margin-left:1080px;
}

#banner {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:175px;
    background-color:Transparent;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
#bannerbg {
    width:930px;
    height:380px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:block;
    background-color:Teal;
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
}
#left {
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:9px;
    margin-top:280px;
    position:absolute;
}
#right {
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:280px;
    margin-left:819px
}
#bot {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#apDiv4").click(function(){
        $("#apDiv1").hide();
        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide';

        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: 'left' };

        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 900;
        $( "#banner" ).show( "slide")
    });
});


    // function vb()
    //{
    //document.getElementById("apDiv1").style.display="none";
    //document.getElementById("banner").style.display="block";
    //}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="frontpage.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="apDiv1">
            <div id="apDiv2">
                <div id="fontmain">xyzef</div>
                <div id="fonttag">kljjhfghjkk</div>
                <div id="apDiv3">Copyright © 2014 ___________.All rights reserved.</div>
            </div>
            <div id="apDiv4">
                <img src="icons/next-arrow-glow.png" width="200" height="200">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="banner"><img id="bot"src="icons/dark_slider_frame.png"/>
            <img id="left" alt="previous" src="icons/left.png"/>
            <img id="right" alt="next" src="icons/right.png"/>
            <div id="bannerbg"></div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must include jQuery as a separate script before you can use its methods.

Comment: you should always google the error before asking a question like this. 
google: "jquery is undefined". you will likely get a stack overflow answer in your first hit.

Comment: It would be **very** surprising if it said "`jQuery` is undefined", as you're not referencing the symbol `jQuery` anywhere in the above. (Now if it said, "`$` is undefined", that would be different...)

Comment: I have had the undefined issue before. Are you doing this locally or from a hosted site??

Comment: i am doing this locally

Comment: make a fiddle.net people understand you better

Comment: You need to download jqueryUI to your local machine, what is happening is your website is loading locally faster than JqueryUI can from a hosted site like google or jquery.com. SO if you download it, it will load faster.

Comment: @Godinall is correct, that would be a far more efficient way to solve the issue is to use jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT

Check Updated [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UVZw2/14/)

I just added position to .banner selector and changed the jQuery to :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#apDiv4").click(function(){
        $("#apDiv1").hide();
         $("#banner").show().animate({'right': '0'},900);
    });
});
```

## Full CSS Update for flexibility

```
html{
height: 100%;

}
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
     background-color:Silver; width:100%; height:100% 
}
.container{ max-width:80%; width:80%; height:800px; position:relative; margin:0px auto; overflow-x:hidden;}
#apDiv1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0px auto;

}
#apDiv2 {   
    min-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    padding: 0;
}
#fontmain {
    font-size:250px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#fonttag {
    font-size:30px;
    padding: 0;
}

#apDiv3 {
    margin-top:260px;
    font-size:90%;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#apDiv4 {
    margin-top:250px;
    float:left; margin:0 30px 0 0;
}

#banner {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:0;
    width:100%!important;
    background-color:Transparent;
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    right:-100%;    
}
#bannerbg {
    width:100%;
    height:380px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    display:block;
    background-color:Teal;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;

}
#left {
    z-index:3;
    left:28px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50%;
}
#right {
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:280px;
    right:20px;
    bottom:50%;
}
#bot {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

## Added Container around the animated div

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="banner"><img id="bot"src="icons/dark_slider_frame.png"/>
        <img id="left" alt="previous" src="icons/left.png"/>
        <img id="right" alt="next" src="icons/right.png"/>
        <div id="bannerbg"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: but the banner is still not sliding on the click event.

Comment: I noticed that the link with the image doesn't have close tag, so I inserted a link in the right (aa) .. click on it the banner will slide. let me know what object you want to click on it to animate the banner.

Comment: $( "#banner" ).show().animate(
            {"left": "-=1860px"},
            "slow");in place of right i took left:-1860

Comment: but the scroll bar moves on doing this how to hide that

Comment: here is a clean link for the above example o let you see better http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/3/show/ . I'm not sure I understand what exactly is your target :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UVZw2/5/ the slide is not coming in jsfiddle but it is coming in my browser when running it through visual studio

Comment: because there is no change between the position of the banner in the CSS and the animate left value ... http://jsfiddle.net/UVZw2/6/ and clean link http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/6/show/

Comment: can u add one change in this http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/6  
i.e. instead of moving from left to right it should move from right to left and horizontal scrollbar should not move

Comment: for the page scroll just add html{overflow-x:hidden; } .. here is the updated http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/9/show/ and the code http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/9/

Comment: on applying your suggestion look what happens to output window is there any way out for this rest everything is fine in this code http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/10/

Comment: why you checking in the code page .. here is the normal page and how your site will look http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/10/show/

Comment: but on minimizing browser all the page will face the same problem

Comment: here is the best result .. a brand new structure http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/14/ and clean view here http://fiddle.jshell.net/UVZw2/14/show